# Why account for censoring in estimating sensitivity but not specificity?

Tags: survival, censoring, sensitivity-specificity

I am reading Tutz & Schmid ["Modeling Discrete Time-to-Event Data"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) (2016) chapter 4 Evaluation and Model Choice section 4.3.3 Discrimination Measures. On p. 94 estimators for sensitivity and specificity in presence of censoring are defined:
$$
\widehat{\text{sens}}(c,t) = \frac{ 
\frac{ \sum_j \delta_j^\mathcal{T} I(\hat\eta_j^\mathcal{T}>c \ \cap \ t_j^\mathcal{T}=t) }{ \hat G_j(t_j^\mathcal{T}-1) }} 
{
\frac{ \sum_j \delta_j^\mathcal{T} I( t_j^\mathcal{T}=t) }{ \hat G_j(t_j^\mathcal{T}-1) }
}
$$
and
$$ 
\widehat{\text{spec}}(c,t) = \frac{ \sum_j I(\hat\eta_j^\mathcal{T}\leq c \ \cap \ t_j^\mathcal{T}>t) }{ \sum_j I( t_j^\mathcal{T}>t) }
$$
where

- $c$ is a threshold value,
- $t$ is time to event (failure),
- $\delta_j^\mathcal{T}$ is an indicator that the observation from the test set (hence the superscript $\mathcal{T}$) on which the estimate is based was *not* censored,
- $\hat\eta_j^\mathcal{T}$ is a predictor (e.g. $\eta=x^\top\gamma$ for some covariates $x$ and a parameter vector $\gamma$) that is transformed into a probability estimate by the inverse link function,
- $\hat G_j$ is a censoring-specific survival function (in the sense of surviving without failure so that the observation may or may not be censored; contrast this to a failed observation that could not be censored).

This is certainly a lot of notation, but it should be possible to follow my question that comes next without understanding it thoroughly.

**Question:** The definition of $\widehat{\text{sens}}(c,t)$ accounts for censoring by inverse probability weighting, i.e. division by censoring-specific survival probability $\hat G_j(t_j^\mathcal{T}-1)$. Meanwhile, the definition of $\widehat{\text{spec}}(c,t)$ does not do that. Why?

[image]

Comment: Sensitivity and specificity apply to retrospectively sample data such as with case-control studies.  Using them for a prospective cohort study muddies the waters,  Look at the conditioning involved with sens and spec; you'll see that it conditions on the unknown to predict what is already known.  Not very helpful.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, is this related to *In Machine Learning Predictions for Health Care the Confusion Matrix is a Matrix of Confusion*? I read it a couple of times before but forgot quite a bit, as I did not work on any related problems since then.

Answer (score 1):

If we indeed follow [Uno et al. (2007)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.993.4993&rep=rep1&type=pdf), we find on p. 16 equations (3.1) and (3.2) that the estimator of specificity **does** include inverse probability weighting due to censoring – just like the estimator of sensitivity. So this seems like a mistake in Tutz & Schmid (2016).